# Null Reference Exception from APIGatewayProxyFunction

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I finally managed to get my API into a state where I can upload it to AWS Lambda, and then I get the error below whenever I try to use the API Gateway to test it.

```json
{
  "errorType": "AggregateException",
  "errorMessage": "One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)",
    "at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)",
    "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , ContextInfo )"
  ],
  "cause": {
    "errorType": "NullReferenceException",
    "errorMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "stackTrace": [
      "at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest)",
      "at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.<FunctionHandlerAsync>d__12.MoveNext()"
    ]
  }
}
```

code:

```cs
public class LambdaEntryPoint : Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
{
    protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        try
        {
            builder
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseApiGateway();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LambdaLogger.Log("Exception throw in LambdaEntryPoint: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get any exceptions logged from my Startup or LambdaEntryPoint. I'm really new to AWS, so I'm not sure what else to check.

Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 2):

This may be the same issue that someone from AWS has addressed with someone else on the AWS github repo for AWS .NET Lambda integration:
https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/168

Comment: Yes, I opened that bug as well. It appears it's something on the AWS side of things vs code related, but I haven't been able to isolate it yet.

Comment: Hi , I have the same exception in NET 6 Service deployed to Lambda. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

check box "Use Lambda Proxy integration" in api gateway method helped me for .net 6 web api.

[image: configuration screenshot]